# Getting permission denied when loading images in train and test dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to load images in x_train, but I am getting an error of not having permission for this.

```
import keras
import tensorflow as tf

train_path = open('C:/Users/dwika/Desktop/catdog/data/train', 'rb')
x_train = []
test_path = open('C:/Users/dwika/Desktop/catdog/data/test', 'rb')
x_test = []

for img in train_path:
    img_path = train_path + img
    x = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(img_path)
    x_train.append(x)

for img in test_path:
    img_path = test_path + img
    x = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(img_path)
    x_test.append(x)
```

I am getting this type of error.

```
 Using TensorFlow backend.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/dwika/Desktop/catdog/catdog.py", line 4, in <module>
 train_path = open('C:/Users/dwika/Desktop/catdog/data/train', 'rb')
 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:'C:/Users/dwika/Desktop/catdog/data/train'
```

Comment: I believe your problem has nothing to do with x_train. As exception reads, there's a permission problem. I'm not sure how permissions work on Windows, but you are likely to solve your problem by ensuring that the file is at the correct path and that the user you're running your script from has access to that file

Comment: make sure you don't have the file open in any other programs?